# When I copy and paste my post URL on any place around social media, it changes its structure

Tags: url, hyperlink

So, no one wants to click and open it. Because it looks like a virus or spam. So, how can I get rid of this horrible and long thing from my web post link, please?

https://readalways.com/%e1%8b%a8%e1%88%9d%e1%88%b5%e1%8c%8b%e1%8a%93-%e1%89%b0%e1%8b%93%e1%88%9d%e1%88%ab%e1%8b%8a-%e1%8a%83%e1%8b%ad%e1%88%8d/
%e1%8b%a8%e1%88%9d%e1%88%b5%e1%8c%8b%e1%8a%93-%e1%89%b0%e1%8b%93%e1%88%9d%e1%88%ab%e1%8b%8a-%e1%8a%83%e1%8b%ad%e1%88%8d/%e1%8b%a8%e1%88%9d%e1%88%b5%e1%8c%8b%e1%8a%93-%e1%89%b0%e1%8b%93%e1%88%9d%e1%88%ab%e1%8b%8a-%e1%8a%83%e1%8b%ad%e1%88%8d/

Answer (score 1):

You can use short links. There are several websites which provide short links instead of long URLs and make redirect to your URL when somebody clicks on a short link.
For example service https://bitly.com/

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But when I share my link, I want it to include and show my website and post title too, so people recognize it immediately. In addition that using link shorteners always is a boring task. When others share my post with their friends they don't know how to short the link or how to remove this so ugly thing! But thank you for your kind answer.